# foreach loop with comma separator causing errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am working on implementing jplayer on my site and need to generate the playlist in php. I've pretty much got comma seperation worked out, but the call i use to get my song url and song title are causing php errors and Im not quite sure what Im doing wrong. Im using social engine an extension of zend. I am normally able to use `<?php echo $this->string()->truncate($song->getTitle(), 50) ?>` and  `<?php $current_url = explode('?', $song->getFilePath());
    echo $current_url[0]; ?>` to generate my mp3 title and url without a problem within the for each loop. My code is below, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
  $count = 0;
  foreach( $songs as $song => $item): if( !empty($song) ): ?>
  <?php if ( $count ) { print ", "; } $count++; ?>

{

    title:"<?php echo $this->string()->truncate($song->getTitle(), 50) ?>",

    mp3:"<?php $current_url = explode('?', $song->getFilePath());
echo $current_url[0]; ?>"

}
<?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

edit: the error im seeing is "Call to a member function getTitle() on a non-object in ...player.tpl "

Comment: Mind telling us what the error is, too?

Comment: Normally `getTitle()` works as expected.

Comment: Where does the variable $songs come from? Can you do a `var_dump($songs)` just before the foreach loop please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using `$song` inside of your loop where you should use `$item`. `$song` is only the array-key, so there no method called `getTitle` while `$item` is your actual object.

Comment: You were right, Im getting sleepy and left that song as item, I got rid of that and things seem to be back on track! Thanks oezi.. most of the time it is the things right in front of us isnt it!